# About Vedic Heaven Deity Dyaus Pita

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, indra

What can you tell me about [Dyaus Pita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyaus)? I've been researching him for an hour, ofc I've been aware of him for the past few months.

In this verse from Mandala 4 of Rik, there is a mention of Dyaus Pita but there is nothing about a heaven or sky or sunlight in verse translation, am I missing something obvious?

[image: Mandala IV - I Hymn - X Verse]

I've also heard that Bhisma from Mahabharata is a rebirth of this *"Dyaus Pita"* is that true?

Apparently i've also heard Dyaus

> - Rapes his daughter Ushas
> - Is seperated from Mother Earth by Indra to create the world

What are the hymns which say so if they do exist that is.